# Trying to set protobuf Map entries in Typescript

Tags: typescript, protocol-buffers, protobuf.js

I have the following protobuf message:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message MyMessage {
  string id = 1;
  map<string, Any> attributeChanges = 2;
}
```

In typescript I am trying to set the map entries of the protobuf message based on a typescript Map that looks like this.

```
type Nullable<T> = T | undefined | null;

export interface IAuditChanges {
  currentValue: Nullable<string>;
  previousValue: Nullable<string>;
  fields?: Map<string, IAuditChanges>
}
```

I try to loop through the entries in the map object and setting the map entries this way.

```
var attributesMap = message.getAttributechangesMap();
for (let key of Array.from(mappedChanges.keys())) {
  const mapEntry: any = mappedChanges.get(key);
  attributesMap.set(key, mapEntry);
}
```

I get the error " TypeError: b.toArray is not a function." Any idea how I can cast / serialize / pack each typescript map entry so that I set it in protobuf? I have looked in a few places for examples without luck.

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#any
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#maps

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Protobuf `Any` is very different from TypeScript `any`. TypeScript `any` allows any possible JavaScript value.

Protobuf `Any` on the other hand is a message with exactly two fields:

1. value: a protobuf message, encoded in binary format
2. type_url: an identifier for the type of the protobuf message

This means you can't just put anything in an `Any` field. It must be a protobuf message, packed into a protobuf `Any`.

The JavaScript reference actually has an example: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/javascript-generated#any

I recommend to write a protobuf message for "IAuditChanges". You most likely won't need `Any` at all.

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I ended up doing.

Comment: The link to the reference is broken.